# Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986. TOMCAT 7.0.78

Tags: tomcat, utf-8

A través de javascript he creado una función para, en un cuadro de texto, meter información. He capado los caracteres especiales y quiero introducir la ñ/Ñ y los acentos. Al rellenar ese cuadro de texto y dar al botón guardar da el error Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986, en mi tomcat con la versión 7.0.78. He mirado en bastantes sitios, y comentaban algo de cambiar el `catalina.properties` y el `server.xml`, los he modificado y sigue dando el mismo error, en la bbdd que es de Oracle también he modificado la codificación a UTF-8 para que admita todos los caracteres pero el Tomcat no me los coge. A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano ya que no se que más buscar. 
En el fichero de catalina.properties he añadido esta línea

```
tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{}
```

y en el server.xml he añadido

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/> la parte URIEncoding.
```

Gracias de antemano.
Saludos!!

---

los servlets que hacen la operación utilizan el método doPost, no se si te refieres a eso. He estado echando un ojo a esos métodos, es válido para cualquier navegador no? Ya que la aplicación de momento solo se utiliza en IE. Y otra pregunta, si ya tengo mi código hecho para que llame a la función que maneja los caracteres que pueden introducir, estas funciones donde debería de implementarlas?

```
function check() {
    // Patron de entrada
    patron1 = /[^a-zA-Z 0-9.]+/g,' '; // mayúsculas, minúsculas, números y espacio
    patron2 = /^[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]*$/; // acentos 
    patron = patron1 + patron2;
    tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
```

Esta es la función para introducir los caracteres que se indican.

Comment: ¿Los caracteres van en la URL o son parte del cuerpo de la petición?

Comment: son parte del cuerpo

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que he estado leyendo este error ocurre cuando la URL contiene caracteres inválidos, no el cuerpo de la petición.

Lo único que se me ocurre es que estás haciendo un GET en lugar de un POST y estás creando una URL como `http://algun_sitio/blah?parametro="años"`.

Si estoy en lo cierto, deberás escapar los caracteres no válidos usando las funciones de javascript [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) o [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)